Configure Nginx to accept requests only from WireGuard clients
I'm trying to install a WireGuard VPN on my server using the setup provided here. My environment configuration includes:
- SERVERURL= auto 
- SERVERPORT= 51820
- PEERS= 2
- INTERNAL_SUBNET= 10.0.0.1
- ALLOWEDIPS= 0.0.0.0/0

After successfully running WireGuard, I use the peer1.conf file in the WireGuard application. Upon checking, my IP changes as expected.
The issue arises when I attempt to restrict access to a specific domain using Nginx, allowing only requests coming through the WireGuard IP. My Nginx configuration looks like this:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name metabase.app.com;
    location / {
        allow 10.0.0.1/24;
        deny all;
    }
}

Despite this setup, Nginx either denies access to all requests or does not correctly identify the WireGuard connection. How can I configure Nginx to accept requests only from WireGuard clients?

Do you want to restrict the access only to this domain or the whole port 80 or 443?
